# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' From windows service

Tags: sql-server

first of all, I was reading almost, all related of **Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'** here and a lot of them in other sites.

My case is a little different:
**My environment**:

- Sql 2017
- Windows  2019 server (No active directory installed)

And a windows service. My windows service is installed as a **Local System**, this service perform automatic updates to some of the databases installed on my Sql2017 Instance, and need to connect to it with **Windows Authentication**.

Things I did:

- User **NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON** already added to Security
  section from Sql 2017 Instance
- User **NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON** added to all databases
  available at Sql 2017 instance
- User **NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON** is active at windows users.
- User **NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM** Has permissions at Sql 2017 instance.

Nothing of it worked.

I have some other customers with:

- Sql 2017 and Server 2012
- Sql 2017 and Win10 pro
- Sql 2008 and server 2012

And everything works fine

Any Ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Your best bet is to use mixed-mode authentication and use a SQL Server account to log in. Failing that, don't run your service as `Local System` but as `Network Service` so you can grant permission to the computer account. If you need more privileges locally than what `Network Service` gives you, set up a dedicated local account and grant it whatever permissions it needs (or if you're lazy, add it to the local administrators group), and create an identical account (same name and password) on the target machine. "Matching accounts" should allow authentication to succeed without a domain.

Comment: Under absolutely no circumstances should you proceed with attempts to give `ANONYMOUS LOGON` permissions of any kind. This is completely insecure on so many interesting levels and shouldn't be done even with a machine that's perfectly firewalled from the outside (which almost no machine is).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Tks for your recomendations. I'm going to take a look on it.